# JQuery Tool similar to Accordion

Tags: jquery

Im interested in implementing a JQuery solution for a Panel Selector that seems very similar to an Accordion.  In this case, the panels remain open and dont close up like an Accordion.

http://www.williamsprofessionalpainting.com/FAQ.php#interior  (Click a FAQ)

My simple question is:  What JQuery tool is this?  Or is there an easy JavaScript solution to implment this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Also here's a quick & dirty example of toggle.http://jsfiddle.net/qfxEg/